# 1,273 rep in a single day - a record?

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, users-page

User 102 (yes, one of the earliest adopters) gained 1,273 rep in a single day, as shown here

https://stackoverflow.com/users/102/bill[image]

How does that happen? The reputation page does not show anything close.

Comment: its a bug ... pretty sure nick will not be happy :)

Comment: in fact ... the whole front user page is looking wacky

Comment: @waffles Yeah, Jon's not at the top left?!

Comment: I ran a few recalcs, but there is something about migration/wikification/closing and such triggering this weirdness ... leaving this open till we fix the root cause

Comment: This is a bug, we're still tracking it down what's causing it though...marking this [status-reproduced] to show we are working on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This turned out to be a bug related to mapping users to questions when content was migrated, it was affecting the wrong user by Id in the wrong database...but should no longer be an issue after the next build.